# How to disable RowHeader on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rowheader

How can I prevent from clicking or selecting `RowHeader`s?
I want that when a new user clicks on a `row` or `cell`, then move all information to an update `Form` and it's working fine.

But, if a user clicks on a `RowHeader`, then it should select all rows and generate an error.

I know I can hide `RowHeader`s, but I want to show `RowHeader`s and I want to prevent users from clicking on them.

I have used the `SelectionMode` property of the `DataGridview` and set it to CellSelect/FullRowSelect etc, but it did not help.

Is it possible to disable `RowHeader`s and not let people select `RowHeader`s?

Here is my code so far:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    decimal accNo = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
    var item = db.UserAccount.Where(a => a.AccountNo == accNo).FirstOrDefault(); 

    txtAccountNo.Text = item.AccountNo.ToString();

    txtFirstName.Text = item.FirstName;
    txtLastName.Text = item.LastName;
    txtAddressUpNew.Text = item.Address.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: @TaW thank you, you are right. I have now edited my question.

Comment: You may want to look into the SelectionMode. Change ftom the default (RowHeader) to something else..

Comment: @TaW thank you again, but as I mentioned in my question I have already tried to solve changing SelecttionMode but did not work for mig.

Comment: CellSelect should work. FullRowSelect  or course not.

Comment: If you want the click on a rowheader to select all rows&cells code the rowheadermouseclick event to do so and, what, create an error? rather unclear specifiction, imo.

Comment: @TaW. I did.  Then if I click somewhere in the rowheader then I get error like "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" I want to prevent clicking the header.

Comment: You should check the columnIndex before using it. For the rowheaders it will be -1. Same for RowIndex when clicking a columnheader. Don't confuse them ;-)

Comment: @TaW thank you. I'am  new for c#. Can you tell me how to check and where to Place maybe in Load_Form? But how can I check?

Comment: If the code you show throws an error in the dataGridView1_CellClick, as you decribe, this is where you should test for a non-negative index. You can't really/easily prevent the user clicking where he want but you can write your code to not always react or to do different things when clicking cells or headers

Comment: @TaW Aha ... if (e.RowIndex > -1) .... OK, thank you. Now it's working

Comment: try to use `RowHeaderMouseClick` event