# Disable DataGridView RowHeader and ColumnHeader from being selected and Click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Are there any method to disable the RowHeader and ColumnHeader from being clicked or selected or mouseClick or mouseHover. Im looking for:

```
dgv.RowHeader.Enable = false;//disable rowheader
```

or

```
dgv.RowHeaderClick += dgv_RowHeaderClick;
private void dgv_RowHeaderClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (sender as DataGridView);

        dgv.RowHeaderClick -= dgv_RowHeaderClick;
    }
```

This is an annoying property of `DataGridView` when a user click on headers, it will highlight and turn blue. Also exception throw sometimes when clicking the cells of headers.

Comment: Related: [How to disable RowHeader on a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233848/how-to-disable-rowheader-on-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind disabling the automatic sort mode of the DataGridView column Headers, you could disable the [Column.SortMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.SortMode);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2), setting it to  [`DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).
This will prevent the colum Header from being highlighted and no sorting glyph is shown.

A Mouse click won't produce any notable effect; the `CellClick` event is raised (with `e.RowIndex = -1`) as usual.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) {
    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

If the DataGridView is bound to a DataSource and it's set to `AutoGenerateColumns`, repeat the procedure if the DataSource is changed.
You could also set this property in the DataGridView designer interface, if the Columns are pre-defined.

For the RowHeader, if needed, you could change the [DataGridView.SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SelectionMode);k(BGMusic.CustomerDataGrid);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to [`DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectionmode?view=netframework-4.7.2).