# Disable "first column header selected" in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to not having the header of the first column selected in a datagridview considering that the  `SelectionMode`  must be set to  `FullRowSelected` .

I tried `EnableHeadersVisualStyles`  to false but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234094/disable-datagridview-rowheader-and-columnheader-from-being-selected-and-click) may help

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.  :(

Comment: Add in app.config: `<runtime><AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=true" /></runtime>` -- See also: [What's new in accessibility in .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#whats-new-in-accessibility-in-the-net-framework-472)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered simply changing the grid's headers `SelectionBackColor` to the default “Control” color… something like…

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
```

Comment: That's right. Combined with `DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False`, which it appears that OP uses already, `DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)` should work.

Comment: `DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` was the property i was looking for. Perfect, it's exactly that and it works perfectly.
Thanks a lot!